# Include/exclude files from jar with maven depending on phase

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a

> src/main/resources/log4j.xml

file which I would like to be included in the jar when I perform a `mvn assembly:assembly` but excluded when I perform a `mvn package`. How could I do this?

I have read several maven docs and questions here but I've been unable so far to do this. I tried many approaches, all of them failed.

Basically, I have in the `<build><plugins>` section of my pom:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and then in the `<build>` section

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>src/main/resources/log4j.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

but I get log4j.xml included everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Anything you place in the `<exclude>` or `<include>` elements is treated as relative to the `<directory>` specified.  So, they way you have it currently, Maven will try to exclude resource `${basedir}/src/main/resources/src/main/resources/log4j.xml` which probably does not exist.  Try setting the resources element like this:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
          <exclude>**/log4j.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
  </resource>
```

As a side note, the `assembly:assembly` goal is deprecated.  Per the [maven-assembly-plugin docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/plugin-info.html), use the `single` goal instead.

Comment: Thanks. This works well excluding log4j.xml from jar either in mvn package and in mvn assembly:single. Now I need to learn how to include it in assembly:single.

Comment: A simple way to do that is to use <fileSets> or <files> in the assembly descriptor.  You may even filter the file if you'd like.  Check the [assembly descriptor docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.maven.plugins` works fine, simple control over including or excluding files in package phase!

```xml
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>
   <configuration>
      <excludes>
         <exclude>**/password.properties</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```